# Mac Terminal: Delete a word at time

Tags: terminal, shortcut, iterm

In [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/), if I type `/one/two/three/four/five` and now if I want to delete `five` and write another string, then how do I delete the word `five` ?

If I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, it deletes the entire command all the way up to the beginning forward slash.

This exact same functionality is available on the out-of-the-box Terminal  using <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> by using <kbd>option</kbd> key as `meta` key. I am running `bash`, but this terminal keyboard combination is not working on iTerm2.

Comment: Your answer should be posted as an answer below! Questions are for asking questions

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. On a pretty "clean slate" macOS install,  Ctrl-W in iTerm deletes the word. (Clean slate meaning other than iTerm, Firefox, and Chrome nothing else has been installed).  Did you customize anything in iTerm?

Answer (score 5):

I just found that in iTerm2, set `options` key as `ESC+` key under `profile -> keys`.