# Customise Mac Terminal command: Control+w

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line

I am trying to find a way to customise Mac Terminal command:**Control+w** which can also consider **delimiters** like **=**, **-**. Currently Space is only way it considers. For example for the command

`$foo --option=foos`

If I use **Control+w**, it deletes **--option=foos** but I want it to delete firstly till **=**, then next delimiter identified, if I pass command once more

Answer (score 2):

Not directly modifying <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, but the same behaviour can be achieved using <kbd>ESC</kbd>  + <kbd>delete</kbd>. Every time, escape key would have to be released and then pressed.

- [Mac Terminal: Delete a word at time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316067/mac-terminal-delete-a-word-at-time)